# How do I avoid false positives when template matching with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to use OpenCV and Python to make a program that checks if a smaller image is inside a larger image.

I know what is inside the larger image, but the smaller image may change every time, so it is important for me to avoid false positives.

I have used `cv2.matchTemplate` with the `cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED` mode to check the confidence, and that works great if the smaller image is simply a cropped version of the full image.

However, issues arise if, for example, the smaller image is a 1x1 white pixel. There is a lot of whitespace in my larger image and I don't want this to match.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2


def main():
    source = cv2.imread('source.png', 0)
    template = cv2.imread('template.png', 0)

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(source, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

    if max_val < 0.9:
        print 'Confidence score is less than 0.9, no match found.'
        return

    print 'Match found!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I improve this? I imagine there would be a way to check if the match is at least a certain size (eg. 50x50) so that the system doesn't break if a tiny image is used as the template, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can add a check on the size of the template you read before calling `matchTemplate`

Comment: Thanks Rick! Although, doing that would cause issues if the template is small because it is shrunk, but should still result in a valid match. That is why I want to check the match size instead of the template

Comment: Well that is true but if the template is 1x1, then the match can't be more than that so that is why I suggested checking the size of the template.

Comment: I used a 1x1 white pixel as an example; the template might be a 100x100 white image. Checking if the template is just a single color probably wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

if the image goes smaller like 1x1, features of image goes too less. It's very hard to match correctly.

You can try other matching algorithms after proper size of template matching.

1. SURF (or SIFT) Matching : https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html

-SURF is an algorithm to make a descriptor of image. It finds several features from image and make a vector of each features. and you can compare the similarity between the features from other image using some distance calculation such as L2-Distance.

.

2. Color Histogram Matching : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching

-Color Histogram is image's own color distribution. You can try to compare similarity of several images using it.

Answer (score 0):

After a positive match using template matching, get the patch from the large image and use more image comparison methods to validate your match. You have to compare two images of the same size. E.g. histogram matching as suggested above, template matching with other norms, comparison of statistics (mean, variance, higher moments), etc.

Another option is to check the score of the "second best match". The score should be smaller than the "best match". This makes sure that there is no other similar patch in your larger image. This should eliminate your "1x1 white pixel" false match.

If your template is rotated, you may need more sophisticated methods to find and extract an initial patch location.

Please keep in mind that it is not possible to avoid false positives in all cases. There should be a counter example always. Especially if your template is small.

For reasonable template sizes, take a look at the recommended patch sizes for feature based matching Methods (SIFT, SURF, ..) or optical flow matching. First guess - your template should be bigger than 21x21 Pixel